# On Unix how to set reliably the width `wget` uses to output its progress bar?

Tags: python, bash, terminal, wget, ioctl

On Unix `wget` determines the width for its progress bar via a call to `ioctl`. In a bash script how can I set reliably the width wget uses?

I tried:

```
#!/bin/bash
stty cols 80
wget <url>
```

but this works not in all calling environments: If I call the script from an interactive bash, it works (i.e the progress bar is 80 cols width), but if I call it from an interactive Python program  it doesn't work (i.e. the progress bar has the width of the calling environment).

How can I write the bash script that it has everything set up so that wget's `ioctl` call returns 80 cols *regardless of the calling environment*?

Comment: What if you also do `export COLUMS=80`?

Comment: @Roadowl wget does not check the `COLUMNS` environment variable. (See in `utils.c` of wget's source code.) I stilled tried it and it doesn't help.

Comment: Perhaps the was it's called from python, the spawned process doesn't have a tty. Can you attach the python programs stdin and stdout to the spawned script? Is there a reason you don't implement the functionality of the script in python instead?

Comment: @glennjackman The Python program is [xonsh](https://xon.sh/) and stdin/out handling in xonsh might be "unconventional" to say the least... I am looking for a totally separate solution: Is it possible to make a bash script (or other intermediate layer) to provide all terminal information, so that subsequent `ioctl` calls get their details from that info?

Comment: @halloleo: Why exactly are you trying to explicitly set the progress bar width? What is your end goal? I'm trying to see if maybe there isn't another way to achieve what you want

Comment: @damir End goal is to limit the progressbar to, say, 80 characters, while my terminal has a (virtual) width of 1000 columns. HTH.